# A method that returns the object that called it

Tags: java

How would I go about creating such a method?
For example, the method that I am currently working on returns an object of an interface that the method's class is implementing. The function of the method is to add an element to a list (*for now the the method returns null because I do not know how to return the desired value):

```
    public ListInterface<T> insertFirst(T item) {
    Arraylist[0] = item;
    return null;
}
```

The constructor of the implementing class (*Arraylist, empty and defCap have already been instantiated at the beginning of the class); I'm assuming that the an object of any class that implements the interface can be the return value of the method above(???); It is also to notice that instantiating an object from the TheList class initialize variables:

```
    public TheList()
{
    Arraylist = (T[]) new Object[defCap];
    empty = true;
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I am asking how to create a method that returns the object that called it (Sorry if that wasn't clear)
Edit: THANK YOU BEN KNOBLE!!

Comment: It's unclear because it's *not* "the object that called it". In the case of `class Thingy {MyList list; void doStuff() {list.insertFirst(null);}}`, and calling `doStuff`, you'd expect "the object that called insertFirst" to be the thingy, not the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` refers to "the current object". To return it, use `return this;`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question then,

```
public ListInterface<T> insertFirst(T item) {
    Arraylist[0] = item;
    return null;
}
```

should be something like

```
public static <T> List<T> insertFirst(T item) {
    List<T> al = new ArrayList<>();
    al.add(item);
    return al;
}
```

which is a method generic on type `T` that returns a `List<T>` of the `item` passed in. You could also use [`Collections.singletonList(T)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList%28T%29)

```
public static <T> List<T> insertFirst(T item) {
    return Collections.singletonList(item);
}
```

Which is immutable, if you need a mutable list you could use my first example or

```
public static <T> List<T> insertFirst(T item) {
    return new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(item));
}
```